# Unable to Parse OVF

Tags: vmware-esxi, ovf

When trying to import an ovf to my ESXi5.1 box via Vmware convertor v4.0 i get the error :

*Unable to parse OVF*

When looking at the logs the only thing I see is

```
[#10] [2013-12-12 08:10:40.494 'App' 2456 info] Could not find the session object cache, will create a new one
[#10] [2013-12-12 08:10:40.494 'App' 2456 verbose] Creating SessionObjectCache
[#10] [2013-12-12 08:10:40.727 'App' 2456 info] OvfParser: ovf file path C:\Users\rick\AppData\Local\Temp\vmware-rick-1000\cpruywucozcgnuky\BIGIP-11.4.1.608.0-scsi.ovf
```

I cant see any files created in there so I suspect an error is occuring to prevent it from being copied across. Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by running ovf tools and then importing it in as a vmx.